# How do I move the table to the vertically center, and align figure and table together?

Tags: floats, horizontal-alignment

```
  \begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \makebox[0.5\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{figure/ch3/result_s2/book.jpg}}
    \qquad \qquad
        \scalebox{0.7}{
    \begin{tabular}[c]{cc}
    \hline
      \textbf{Method} & \textbf{$\sigma$} \\ \hline
      method 1 & 0.0 \\
      method 2 & 0.1 \\
      method 3 & 0.2 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}}
  \end{figure}
```

Please help!, Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?
[image]

Code:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{graphicx}

   \usepackage[active,floats,tightpage]{preview}
   \setlength\PreviewBorder{5mm}

        \begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \raisebox{-13mm}{
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image}
                        }
        \hfil
        \begin{tabular}[b]{cc}
        \hline
          \textbf{Method} & \textbf{$\sigma$} \\ \hline
          method 1 & 0.0 \\
          method 2 & 0.1 \\
          method 3 & 0.2 \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \caption{May figure accompanied with table}
    \end{figure}
        \end{document}
```

For vertical centering I use `\raisebox`. Amount for lowering of figure you need select according to size of original picture.

Answer (score 2):

Use `\raisebox{-0.5\height}{...}`, so the image will be vertically centered without any need to guess at its height.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering

\raisebox{-.5\height}{%
  \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{example-image}%
}\hfill
{\footnotesize
 \begin{tabular}[c]{cc}
 \hline
 \textbf{Method} & \textbf{$\sigma$} \\ \hline
 method 1 & 0.0 \\
 method 2 & 0.1 \\
 method 3 & 0.2 \\ \hline
 \end{tabular}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Avoid `\scalebox` in this case: choosing `\footnotesize` is better.

[image]

Comment: Good to know, that the height of image can be used outside of ``\includegraphics``.